# How to select everything that contains a determined string in Atom's colorscheme?

Tags: css, less, atom-editor

Right now, in my custom scheme, if I write `"SELECT * FROM table"`, I have the following colors:

- orange: ", table
- blue: SELECT, FROM
- pink: *

That's because I'm using orange for strings and punctuation marks, blue for keywords and pink for operators.

Digging with the developer tools I found that when a string is actually a SQL query, it has the `sql` word at some point in the CSS chain. For instance, the above sentence is:

```
<span class="string quoted double single-line sql python">
    <span class="punctuation definition string begin python">"</span>
    <span class="keyword other DML sql">SELECT</span> 
    <span class="keyword operator star sql">*</span> 
    <span class="keyword other DML sql">FROM</span> table<span class="punctuation definition string end python">
    </span>
</span>
```

So my question is, is it possible to write some rule so that I could apply orange to everything that contains the word `sql`? I'm not interested in changing the overall keywords and operators colors, just for the SQL queries.

Something like `$.*sql* { color: @orange; }`, but obviously this doesn't work.

Comment: if you want to apply orange to everything that contains the class `sql` just use css `.sql{color: orange}`

Comment: @John ok, didn't know I could do that. I thought I must follow the CSS path :) Write an answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
.sql{
   color: orange;
}
```

it will give orange color to all elements with class `sql`